# Advantage of using a contract constructor with parameters

Tags: contract-design, constructor

What is the advantage of using a constructor with parameters instead of hard coding the values? Is there a possibility to reuse a once deployed contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes for easier code reuse. E.g. you can compile a contract once and then deploy it twice with different parameters. You can also inherit the same base contract in two different derived contracts and pass different parameters to the base constructor.